# Jupyter Notebook Taskbar/toolbar not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been trying to find an answer to this problem for a while now, but I can't seem to find the right answer. When I am in jupyter, I can open a notebook and I can code in it, however, the taskbar that has "File, Edit, View, Insert, Cell, etc." is no longer functional. When I click the buttons, nothing happens. I can't make any new files as well for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem.
I don't know why but I delete ipython log, after then I can click my taskbar.
You can try.
`rm -rf ~/.ipython`